# Amazon Linux AMI EC2- Missing packages

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Following this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

I've been stuck trying to install a LAMP web server on putty because the packages appear to be missing!

I'll take you through the steps:-

1) `sudo yum update -y`
3) `sudo yum install -y httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd`

Then I get the following:-

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No package httpd24 available.
No package php70 available.
No package mysql56-server available.
No package php70-mysqlnd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

4) `sudo yum repolist all`

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, priorities, update-motd
repo id                             repo name                     status
!amzn2-core/2017.12/x86_64          Amazon Linux 2 core repositor enabled: 7,711
amzn2-core-debuginfo/2017.12/x86_64 Amazon Linux 2 core repositor disabled
amzn2-core-source/2017.12           Amazon Linux 2 core repositor disabled
repolist: 7,711
```

What am I missing??

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You're using an Amazon Linux **2** instance (as shown by the `amzn2-core` references in the `yum repolist all` output), but trying to use the tutorial for Amazon Linux **1**. Try [this tutorial instead](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html).

Comment: can you post a short note instead of the link ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this instead:

```
yum update -y
amazon-linux-extras install -y php7.4
yum install -y httpd
```